# PUTing files into S3 using Python requests

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, python-requests

I've got this URL that was generated using the `generate_url(300, 'PUT', ...)` method and I'm wanting to use the [requests library](http://python-requests.org/) to upload a file into it.

This is the code I've been using: `requests.put(url, data=content, headers={'Content-Type': content_type})`, I've also tried some variations on this but the error I get is always the same.

I get a 403 - `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error from S3 every time, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044151/how-to-generate-a-temporary-url-to-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-with-boto-library

Answer (score 1):

Using `boto3`, this is how to generate an upload url and to `PUT` some data in it:

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id="XXX", aws_secret_access_key="XXX")
s3client = session.client('s3')
url = s3client.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={'Bucket': 'mybucket', 'Key': 'mykey'})

requests.put(url, data=content)
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 requires authentication token if your bucket is not public write. Please check token.

I would suggest you to use [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) directly.

```
bucket.new_key()
key.name = keyname
key.set_contents_from_filename(filename, {"Content-Type": content_type})
# optional if file public to read
bucket.set_acl('public-read', key.name)
```

Also please check did you add Content-Length header. It's required and take part in auth hash calculation.

Comment: Could you please provide a source for that? AFAICT it's no different than `generate_url(300, 'GET', ...)` when it comes to permissions.

Comment: I checked docs, you're right there is no difference for auth. Probably you missed headers for generate_url.

Comment: That sounds about right, I didn't specify any, what headers are required? (Ah, I didn't see edit, Content-Length).

Comment: I think Content-Length is, not sure about others

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.

It seems the signature had a signed header "host" so it has to be included in the request you send as well.

```
s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name=<region>,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
kwargs = {
    "ClientMethod": "put_object",
    "Params": {
        "Bucket": <bucket>,
        "Key": <file key>,
    },
    "ExpiresIn": 3600,
    "HttpMethod": "PUT",
}
s3_client.generate_presigned_url(**kwargs)
with open(<my_file>, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
response = requests.put(url, data=data, headers={"host": "<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com"})
```