# How to retrieve amazon s3 temporary credentials?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, credentials

I've got a Django Rest API and a React Native app. I'd like to upload some files to my s3 bucket from my app.

I could do this :

1. User would like to upload an image --> GET my_api/s3/credentials/
2. App --> POST image directly to s3 using credentials (access/private keys)

The problem is that once the user has the accessKey and privateKey, he can use it indefinitely.

Is there a way to retrieve temporary credentials I could give to the user after a call on my_api/s3/credentials/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer. It is possible to generate from server side a temporary URL to POST your content.

[details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34464198/4297562)